# JavaFX - How to sort values in a BarChart

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, bar-chart

I have the following JavaFX BarChart (NumberAxis on the bottom, CategoryAxis on the left):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpiu1.png

How can I reverse (i.e. sort by value) the order of the categories, so that J shows at the top and A at the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, "A"));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, "B"));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, "C"));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, "D"));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, "E"));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, "F"));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, "G"));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, "H"));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, "J"));

Collections.sort(series1.getData(), new Comparator<XYChart.Data>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Data o1, Data o2) {
        Number xValue1 = (Number) o1.getXValue();
        Number xValue2 = (Number) o2.getXValue();
        return new BigDecimal(xValue1.toString()).compareTo(new BigDecimal(xValue2.toString()));
    }
});
```

Comment: For me, this is actually just inserting the Data in the given order. If I do 

`series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(4, "H"));
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(1, "B")); 
series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(2, "F"));
Collections.sort(...); //as in suggested code`

the BarChart will display the bars in the given order and not sort anything.

Comment: Strange. Please write the sort that is in your code, because this works. new Comparator<XYChart.Data>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Data o1, Data o2) {
        Number xValue1 = (Number) o1.getXValue();
        Number xValue2 = (Number) o2.getXValue();
        return new BigDecimal(xValue1.toString()).compareTo(new BigDecimal(xValue2.toString()));
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

The chart data could be sorted in the decreasing order of their sizes so that the category axis is always sorted .

```
bc.getData().sort((Series<String, Number> o1, Series<String, Number> o2) -> o1.getData().size() <= o2.getData().size()?1:0);
```

Comment: please don't post the same answer to multiple questions. Chances are, that the questions are duplicates and should be marked as such. If not, tailor your answers to each question to note why/how they are different.